# Angular, connect objects and display right information

Tags: javascript, angularjs, api, primary-key

I'm creating an angular webapp, listing different cars in a sidebar and some information about the specific car in a informationbox.

The purpose is to show the right information in the box when clicking the different cars.

I have two different arrays(two API-endpoints), where the first array lists the car name, and the other one got the information about the car. But I have no idea how to connect the objects with the primary key and the foreign key, and how I'm supposed to output the right information after clicking the car.

app.js:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('MyController', function($scope, $http) {

    function fetch() {

        $http({method : 'GET',url : 'http://*cars*'})
            .success(function(data) {
                $scope.cars = data;
            });

        $http({method : 'GET',url : 'http://*information*'})
            .success(function(data) {
                $scope.information = data;
            });

    }

    fetch();

})
```

html:

```
<div id="sidebar">

            <ul>

                <li ng-repeat="name in cars"><a href="#">{{ name.displayName }}</a></li>

            </ul>

</div>
```

For now all I have done is that I've fetched the data and outputed the cars in the sidebar. But now I've been googling and trying to connect the cars to the information with loops and functions for hours, but stil clueless.

Yes, I'm new to this. Any kind of help would be great! Thanks

Comment: Why don't you use a single array to store the cars and their information and just display the information of a selected car?

Answer (score 0):

You can deal with this with the ng-route. You can do something like :

In your route definition:

```
.when(/cars/:Id), {
            name: 'cars',
            templateUrl : 'ayourtemplate.html',
            controller : 'yourCtrl'
        })
```

In your html:

```
<div id="sidebar">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="name in cars"><a href="cars/1515">{{ name.displayName }}</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The Id will be your key tou will just have to match the right key in your $scope.information

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what information those arrays contains.
If you're sure, that every element corresponds to other, you can just use `$index` in the html.

```
<li ng-repeat="name in cars">
    <a href="#">{{ name.displayName }}</a>
    <p>{{ information[$index] }}</p>
</li>
```

However, if elements in array aren't ordered, you will have to check primary keys of objects in arrays. Let's assume, that data in arrays looks like this:

```
cars:
[
    { id: "1", name: "Carrera GT" },
    { id: "2", name: "DB 11" },
... and so on
]

information:
[
    { id: "2", info: "Lorem ipsum" },
    { id: "1", info: "Dolor sit amet" }, 
...
]
```

Then I'd suggest using loops and constructing new array using ids.

```
    var carinfo = [];
    cars.forEach(car => {
        obj["id"] = car.id;
        obj["name"] = car.name;
        obj["info"] = ""; // Placeholder

        info.forEach(c => {
            if (c.id === car.id) {
                obj["info"] = c.info;
            }
        });

        carinfo.push(obj);
    });
    $scope.carInfo = carinfo;
```

Then you can use `$scope.carInfo` in the html file.

```
<li ng-repeat="car in carInfo">
    <a href="#">{{ car.name }}</a>
    <p>{{ car.info }}</p>
</li>
```

Comment: Thank you verry much! $index works perfectly and outputs the right data :) I'll try the second solution for good practice. Things similar to that I've been trying to do but failed